# Sitefinity 8.1 MVC Hyphen issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, sitefinity

I'm having an issue with a sitefinity application. I'm using MVC 5 which comes with sitefinity 8.1. My problem is that when I use hyphens in the actionresult name, I receive a 404 error on request.

```
    [ActionName("some-thing")]
    public ActionResult PersonalChecking(string prodid = null)
    {
        var model = new OACWidgetModel();

        return View(model);
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out why it wasn't working.
Apparently, Sitefinity requires that EnableBackwardCompatabilityForPagesUrls be turned on for special character in action names.

To enable this, go to Administation->Settings->Advanced->Pages and check the checkbox named EnableBackwardCompatabilityForPagesUrls and press the button Save Changes.

Fixed! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the Route attribute instead of the ActionName one.

```
[Route("some-thing")]
public ActionResult PersonalChecking(...)
{...}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, indeed actionName doesn't working in MVC 5. That may explain why the code worked in Sitefinity 7.

I tried you suggestion, but i still get a 404 when I request localhost:80/somepagename/some-thing.

I found this article http://docs.sitefinity.com/feather-use-the-relative-routes-api that shows the use of RelativeRoute, but that doesn't seem to work either.

The article says then when the RelativeRoute is used, there is no need to call MapMvcAttributeRoutes.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Just to confirm - does the somepagename page actually contains the MVC widget? Does the widget have an Index method? Does it get invoked upon initial loading of the page? 
Can you put a breakpoint in the PErsonalChecking method and see if it gets invoked too.

Comment: Yes, it does have the widget on the page. And yes when I loaded the page in debug mode I  can get the index action to work fine. All the action that don't contain a hyphen seem to work just fine.

Comment: The debugger even shows that action being caught and that it executes all the code within. It even returns the view. but the page  still responds in a 404. See below.

Detailed Error Information:
Module    ManagedPipelineHandler
Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    ASP.sfpageservice_82fceb89_482c_60e9_9cca_ff0000fbfb2a_notheme_aspx
Error Code    0x00000000